# How do I move specific valued cells in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, csv, if-statement

I am working with a dataset that contains both numbers and names. In the dataset, some numbers and names are displayed and instead of manually going through thousands of rows I tried to make a script but it doesn´t happen anything.
Here is the code:

```
Sub MoveCells()
    Dim row As Long

    For row = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("C" & row).Value Like "*0*" Then
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To 2
                Range("C" & row).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Next
        End If
        Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to move the cell that has a 0 in it, and the cell to the right of it, one step to right.
E.g. Cells C4 & D4 to D4 & E4.

Comment: Some notes: Fully qualify your range references to the actual workbook/worksheet parent, define `LastRow`, don't overload existing properties like `.Row` with the same variable name, looks like an apparently needless `For i = 1 to 2` loop executing the same thing twice. Side note: `Like "*0*"` would accept any empty cell as well :-; @terriblescoder

Comment: The notes worked perfectly!! Thank you so much! The headaches are finally over!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some adjustments to your code which will acheive the outcome you described.

```
Private Sub MoveCells()
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ColumnCValue As Variant
    Dim ColumnDValue As Variant
    
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row
    End With

    For TargetRow = 2 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & TargetRow).Value Like "*0*" Then
            ColumnCValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & TargetRow).Value
            ColumnDValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & TargetRow).Value
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & TargetRow).Value = ColumnCValue
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & TargetRow).Value = ColumnDValue
            
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & TargetRow).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now we first assign a value to for `LastRow` and when the `If...Then` statement is true, assign the values of `Column C` and `Column D` to the respective variables. Then, write those values 1 row to the right and finally clear the contents from Column C.